# Render two table rows inside .map() in react or preact

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

i wan to display two rows for each data inside map, for example i have data object called `productResponse` then i want to render like this snippet

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Product Group</th>
        <th class="text-center">Taxable</th>
        <th class="text-center">Tax Included</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sonair</td>
        <td>Customer-focused hybrid orchestration</td>
        <td>gtr</td>
        <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-check text-info"></i></td>
        <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-check text-info"></i></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="6">append here</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Biodex</td>
        <td>Open-source attitude-oriented strategy</td>
        <td>Sepatu Bola</td>
        <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-times text-danger"></i></td>
        <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-times text-danger"></i></td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="6">append here</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

here is my code to iterate the data

```
let header =
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Product Group</th>
        <th class="text-center">Taxable</th>        
        <th class="text-center">Tax Included</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    let body =[];
    productResponse.map((d,i)=>(

        body.push(<tr>
            <td>{d.name}</td>
            <td>{d.description}</td>
            <td>{d.product_group.name}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{d.is_taxable?<i class="fa fa-check text-info"></i>:<i class="fa fa-times text-danger"></i>}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{d.is_tax_included?<i class="fa fa-check text-info"></i>:<i class="fa fa-times text-danger"></i>}</td>
            <td>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" onClick={this.edit.bind(this,d)}><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" onClick={this.deleteData.bind(this,d)}><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
            </div>
            </td>

        </tr>);
        body.push(<tr><td colspan="6">append here</td><tr>);
    ))
    return [header,body];
```

but it seems we cant have two tr, what should i do?

Comment: *"...but it seems we cant have two tr..."* What makes you think that? What error do you get? Or what incorrect result?

Comment: Note: Using `map` when you're not using the array it returns is an anti-pattern. Just use a loop, or `forEach`.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it says that expression must have one parent element, it's work with one tr, but no with two tr

Comment: You can use a fragment in that situation. But if you gave us an MCVE, we might be able to suggest a better overall solution.

Answer (score 1):

You've said the error you're getting is:

> it says that expression must have one parent element, it's work with one tr, but no with two tr

Often when that's the case, the solution is to use a [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactfragment):

```
<React.Fragment>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
</React.Fragment>
```

with newer versions of React, you can use the shorter form `<>...</>`:

```
<>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
</>
```

But sometimes, you can restructure things so you don't need to do that, based on the overall context.

If you can't use fragments, you can usually put a wrapper element (`div`, `span`) around the elements. In this case, a `tbody`:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: unfotyunately i use preact, is there another approach?

Comment: @MatiusNugrohoAryanto - preact doesn't have fragments?! In this specific case you could use a `tbody`, but again, if you provide a MCVE, there's probably a better solution.